# Matrix multiplication as composition

Tags: matrices, geometry, analytic-geometry

I've been trying to brush up on linear algebra, and I've encountered a problem that I haven't been able to resolve on my own.

A couple of days ago I watched a great video: **"Matrix multiplication as composition | Chapter 4, Essence of linear algebra"**. In this video the author writes down an expression that shows how multiplication of 2 matrices (representing 2 different linear transformations) captures the overall / simultaneous effect of 2 linear transformations:

[Matrix multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av3yW.png)  (1)

One thing I can't wrap my head around is how to prove that the second transformation should be applied to the product of the first transformation and a vector we are transforming.

To figure out what coordinates vector $\bar v$ will have in the original basis after a linear transformation, we use the following formula:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    v1 \\
    v2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a11 & a12 \\
    b21 & a22 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    v'1 \\
    v'2 \\
    \end{bmatrix},\tag{*}\label{*}
$$

where $\begin{bmatrix}
    a11 & a12 \\
    b21 & a22 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
is the matrix that shows what coordinates our new basis vectors will have (with regard to the original basis) after a linear transformation is applied, $\begin{bmatrix}
    v'1 \\
    v'2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ are coordinates of a transformed vector in the new basis.

---

I've written down a very informal proof of this formula: [Matrix vector multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G3IG.png).

---

Turning back to the formula that is given in the video (1), I want to understand why do we multiply the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
    c11 & c12 \\
    d21 & d22 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
by the vector
$\begin{bmatrix}
    v1 \\
    v2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ $\eqref{*}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    c11 & c12 \\
    d21 & d22 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \left(\begin{bmatrix}
    a11 & a12 \\
    b21 & a22 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    v'1 \\
    v'2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

I have this question because in the formula $\eqref{*}$ we use $\begin{bmatrix}
    v'1 \\
    v'2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ but not
$\begin{bmatrix}
    v1 \\
    v2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$.

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Frankly speaking, I'm totally confused, despite the fact that I see that numerically everything adds up.

Comment: There's no change of basis involved.  The first transformation $T_1$ takes the vector $v_1$ to some other vector $v_2$.  We apply the second $T_2$ transformation to $v_2$.  Multiplication of $v_1$ by the matrix corresponding to $T_1$ gives $v_2$ in the same basis as $v_1$.

Comment: @ saulspatz, yes, I agree, I mixed up several topics as they go hand in hand ... However, the question remains the same. For instance, we have a basis $(i;j)$: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$. Let's consider a simple rotation matrix that transforms our $i$ and $j$ to $i_t$ and $j_t$:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$ In order to see where $i$ and $j$ land in the basis $(i;j)$ after this rotation ($A$), we multiply $A$ by $i_t$ and and $j_t$:

Comment: $$A*i_t=A\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix};A*j_t=A\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The same we can do with any other vectors. After that we want to use a shear matrix:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$ I don't understand why we multiply $B$ by $i_t\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ and $j_t\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ in the basis $(i;j)$. Because just before that we multiplied $A$ (a different transformation) by $i_t\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ and $j_t\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ in the basis $(i_t;j_t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $m \times n$ matrix $A \in M(m \times n, \mathbb{R})$ encodes a linear transformation $L_A \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by the following rule: $L_Ae_j = a_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$, where $a_j \in \mathbb{R}^m$ denotes the $j$th column of $A$ and $e_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $j$th standard basis vector.

Now given another matrix $B \in M(k \times m, \mathbb{R})$, $B$ encodes a linear transformation $L_B \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^k$ just as $A$ does, i.e., $L_Be_i = b_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$. The matrix product $BA \in M(k \times n, \mathbb{R})$ is defined so that $L_{BA} = L_BL_A$, that is,
\begin{align}
(BA)_j &:= L_BL_Ae_j \\
&= L_Ba_j \\
&= L_B\sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ij}e_i \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ij}L_Be_i \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{m}a_{ij}b_i.
\end{align}
So the fact that matrix multiplication is composition is really the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. I think (hope) I am starting to understand. Could you please answer me 1 more question? Taking into account that a matrix $A$, representing a certain linear transformation $L_a$, is based on (defined) by basis vectors that get transformed, the resulting basis vectors (after a transformation is applied) can be treated as "new" basis vectors that we can transform again, multiplying them by a matrix $B$, for example. Is it right? Or I am interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: @Suprematism No, the vectors $\{Ae_j\}$ won't necessarily be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. What you can say is $$BA = \begin{bmatrix}BAe_1 & \dots & BAe_n \end{bmatrix},$$ which is essentially the definition of matrix multiplication. Usually people write $A = L_A$ because they are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!